# High variance across k-fold CV classification accuracy estimates

Tags: classification, cross-validation

I'm tackling a binary classification task, data is class-balanced. I'm training a multi-layer perceptron on this data. To estimate accuracy on unseen samples, I decided to perform $10$-fold cross validation. However, estimated validation accuracies on the $10$ folds have high variance ($\mu \simeq 63\%, \sigma \simeq 3\%$).

My first reaction was suspecting this is due to the random initialization of the neural network and local minima. So I  decided to repeat the training/validation for each fold, to see if the variance was caused by local minima. I was wrong. The model does a consistent job within the same fold, it appears that some folds are "easier" than others.

What does this tell me about the dataset? What can be done further to have a better estimate?

Comment: Couple of questions here: 
Why use a shallow neural network with CV? This is old school.
Did you try other learning algorithms, e.g. Random Forest or XGBoost?
Did you have a look at accuracy metrics such as precision/recall per class?

Comment: @Digio my data is very high-dimensional, and I will form an ensemble of the resulting networks after CV.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what made you follow this specific approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few thoughts:

- for a (true) accuracy of $p = 63\,\%$, a standard deviation of the observed accuracy $s_{\hat p}$ of 3 % would be expected for testing with roughly 250 cases (using binomial distribution):
  $$s_{\hat p} = \sqrt{\frac{p (1-p)}{n_{tested}}}$$

  As you compare observed accuracy across folds, that would be 250 cases *in each fold*. So if your data set isn't $\gg$ 2500 cases, you probably just ran into the fact that accuracy (and other figures of merit that are fractions of tested cases) has rather bad variance properties.
- Of course, you can also accidentally run into easy or difficult train/test splits for the surrogate models.
  You can separate this instability wrt. exchanging training cases from the variance due to the tested cases above using iterated/repeated k-fold cross validation: repeating the 10-fold with different 10 splits allows you directly to compare predictions for the same case but predicted by models obtained from slightly different training sets. See e.g. our paper [Beleites, C. & Salzer, R.: Assessing and improving the stability of chemometric models in small sample size situations, Anal Bioanal Chem, 390, 1261-1271 (2008). DOI: 10.1007/s00216-007-1818-6](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00216-007-1818-6)
- And, as your classifier isn't fully deterministic, that is another source of variance (which you've already ruled out).